# Mysql Insert data in third table based on data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have the below tables:

`order_temp` table

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      order_id       |    sap_number    |   product_name   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         123      |     earphones    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         123      |      battery     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         456      |      charger     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         789      |       phone      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

`order` table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      order_id       |    sap_number    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         123      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         456      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         789      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to insert data in order_item table which should have the same order_id if the sap_number is same. It should look like this:

`order_item` table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     order_item_id   |     order_id     |   product_name   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |     earphones    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |      battery     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         2        |      charger     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         3        |       phone      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Please help me with an insert query for order_item table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way you can do this is using sub queries:

```
INSERT INTO order_item(order_id, product_name)
VALUES ((SELECT order_id,product_name FROM order
         INNER JOIN order_temp ON order.sap_number = order_temp.sap_number);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use with this simple query :

```
INSERT INTO order_item (order_id,product_name)
    SELECT b.order_id,a.product_name
    FROM order_temp a 
left join order b 
on a.sap_number=b.sap_number
```